# How to get the index of a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to get the index of a ListBoxItem in WP8.... And this is my XAML code

```
  <phone:PivotItem Header="Pins">
            <!-- Content Panel -->
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="583" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="87*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ListBox x:Name="lstData2"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection2, Source={StaticResource PinsCollection}}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Foreground="#FF1D53D0" Height="583" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate  >
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tap="StackPanel_Tap" MouseLeftButtonDown ="SetIndex" Tag="{Binding pinId}">
                                <Image Margin="8"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    Source="{Binding ImageUri}"
                                    Width="100"
                                    Height="100" />
                                <StackPanel Height="93" Width="259" >
                                    <TextBlock Margin="8"
                                        Width="250"

                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Foreground="#FF1D53D0"
                                        Text="{Binding Pinnedname}"  Height="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                    <TextBlock Width="155"
                                        Margin="8,0,8,8"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                        Text="{Binding Status}" Foreground="#FF1D53D0" FontFamily="Segoe WP SemiLight" />

                                </StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove Pin" Click="RemovePin_Click"/>

                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <!-- End of Content Panel -->
            </Grid>
        </phone:PivotItem>
```

I want to get the index in the SetIndex event handler in the MouseLeftButtonDown!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a two-way binding for that:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstData2" SelectedIndex="{Binding Index,Mode=TwoWay}"
```

There's generally no need to add click handlers for ListBox, as most basic click functionality is built into the control.

Comment: mm sorry but can you help me in one more thing
i do have that function that i want to get the index in it ... 
and when i use SelectedIndex it returns me -1 and i must press the element again to get the right inex 
i mean that the index is always 1 step behind

Comment: That's because mouseleftbuttondown fires before the selection changed event.  If you want the selected index, use the listbox selection change event instead.